# AngularJS: Resolving promise in ui-router config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

There is code of mine $stateProvider:

```
$stateProvider
  .state("home", {
      url: "/",
      template: "<employee-info-component user='$resolve.user'></employee-info-component>",
      resolve: {
        user: function(individualFootprintService) {
          var usr = individualFootprintService.getCurrentUser();
          return usr.then(function(data) {
            return data;
          });
        }
      }
```

It's my service:

```
function getCurrentUser() {
  return $http
    .get("/user")
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
}
```

This is my binding in component:

```
        binding:{
                user: '<'
        }
```

We tried this controller:

```
function individualFootprintController(user) {
        var $ctrl = this;
user.then(function (data) {
            $ctrl.user = data;
        });
}
```

But we are receiving exception 
`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: userProvider <- user <- individualFootprintController`

And we tried this controller:

```
function individualFootprintController() {
            var $ctrl = this;
            console.log($ctrl.user);
    }
```

But `user` don't comes to the controller and its value is `undefined`. 
So my question is how can i get access to the desired object from the controller?

Comment: resolve should directly work on promises, and inject the value resolved (by then) and you should not resolve promise in controller. have you tried removing all the ".then (function )"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `bindings` instead of `binding`.